# Why sometimes there are multiple JSF life cycles invoked?

Tags: jsf, facelets, lifecycle

I connected a simple jsf lifecycle listener to my webbapp:

```
public class LifeCycleListener implements PhaseListener 
{

@Override
public PhaseId getPhaseId() {
    return PhaseId.ANY_PHASE;
}

@Override
public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {
    System.out.println("START PHASE " + event.getPhaseId());
}

@Override
public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) {
    System.out.println("END PHASE " + event.getPhaseId());
}

}
```

On one of the pages I have smth like this:

```
<h:form>
  <h:commandLink id="avdertAddedToMainPage" action="#{topView.showMainPage}">
      Main Page
  </h:commandLink>
</h:form>
```

where topView is simple bean configured in faces-config as request-scoped:

```
public class TopView {

public TopView() {
}

public String showAddAdvert()
{
    return "addAdvert";
}

public String showMainPage()
{
    return "itemList";
}

}
```

What makes me wonder is that, if I click the above link, everything seems to work properly, but according to LiceCycleListener's output every phase is run by 2 times (yesterday I count 4 times but it was because of issue with threads) before page loads up. Is this normal behaviour? If this indicates some kind of bug in my code, where I should look for it?

I use Mojarra 2.0.2 on Glassfish 3.0.1

Here is my output from today's try. There are only two rounds of lifecycle, but yesterday I had 4. When I look at yestarday's logs I discovered that I had more than one thread, so I guess that it had smth to do with modifying my app while server was running. But still I don't know if the 2-rounds of lifecycle is a good thing. Also note there are few warnings about setting character encoding but I don't know if this matters.

```
FINE: [Web-Security] Policy Context ID was: Powypadkowe/Powypadkowe
FINE: [Web-Security] hasUserDataPermission perm: (javax.security.jacc.WebUserDataPermission /faces/AdvertAddedCl.xhtml POST)
FINE: [Web-Security] hasUserDataPermission isGranted: true
FINE: [Web-Security] Policy Context ID was: Powypadkowe/Powypadkowe
FINE: [Web-Security] hasResource isGranted: true
FINE: [Web-Security] hasResource perm: (javax.security.jacc.WebResourcePermission /faces/AdvertAddedCl.xhtml POST)
WARNING: PWC4011: Unable to set request character encoding to UTF-8 from context /powypadkowe, because request parameters have already been read, or ServletRequest.getReader() has already been called
WARNING: PWC4011: Unable to set request character encoding to UTF-8 from context /powypadkowe, because request parameters have already been read, or ServletRequest.getReader() has already been called
INFO: START PHASE RESTORE_VIEW 1
INFO: END PHASE RESTORE_VIEW 1
INFO: START PHASE APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2
INFO: END PHASE APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2
INFO: START PHASE PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3
INFO: END PHASE PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3
INFO: START PHASE UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES 4
INFO: END PHASE UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES 4
INFO: START PHASE INVOKE_APPLICATION 5
INFO: END PHASE INVOKE_APPLICATION 5
INFO: START PHASE RENDER_RESPONSE 6
INFO: ------- some hibernate sql selects -------
INFO: END PHASE RENDER_RESPONSE 6
FINE: SecurityContext: setCurrentSecurityContext method called
FINE: [Web-Security] Policy Context ID was: Powypadkowe/Powypadkowe
FINE: [Web-Security] hasUserDataPermission perm: (javax.security.jacc.WebUserDataPermission /faces/photos/nowy17@mail.pl/Atojest/item_1/1m.jpg GET)
FINE: [Web-Security] hasUserDataPermission isGranted: true
FINE: [Web-Security] Policy Context ID was: Powypadkowe/Powypadkowe
FINE: [Web-Security] hasResource isGranted: true
FINE: [Web-Security] hasResource perm: (javax.security.jacc.WebResourcePermission /faces/photos/nowy17@mail.pl/Atojest/item_1/1m.jpg GET)
WARNING: PWC4011: Unable to set request character encoding to UTF-8 from context /powypadkowe, because request parameters have already been read, or ServletRequest.getReader() has already been called
WARNING: PWC4011: Unable to set request character encoding to UTF-8 from context /powypadkowe, because request parameters have already been read, or ServletRequest.getReader() has already been called
INFO: START PHASE RESTORE_VIEW 1
INFO: END PHASE RESTORE_VIEW 1
INFO: START PHASE APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2
INFO: END PHASE APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2
INFO: START PHASE PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3
INFO: END PHASE PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3
INFO: START PHASE UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES 4
INFO: END PHASE UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES 4
INFO: START PHASE INVOKE_APPLICATION 5
INFO: END PHASE INVOKE_APPLICATION 5
INFO: START PHASE RENDER_RESPONSE 6
INFO: END PHASE RENDER_RESPONSE 6
FINE: SecurityContext: setCurrentSecurityContext method called
```

And the fragment of yestarday's log:

```
[#|2012-06-04T22:05:49.158+0200|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=30;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|END PHASE UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES 4|#]

[#|2012-06-04T22:05:49.158+0200|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=33;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|START PHASE RESTORE_VIEW 1|#]

[#|2012-06-04T22:05:49.161+0200|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=31;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|START PHASE RENDER_RESPONSE 6|#]

[#|2012-06-04T22:05:49.162+0200|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=33;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|END PHASE RESTORE_VIEW 1|#]

[#|2012-06-04T22:05:49.163+0200|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=33;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|START PHASE APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2|#]

[#|2012-06-04T22:05:49.261+0200|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=32;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|START PHASE APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2|#]

[#|2012-06-04T22:05:49.261+0200|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=33;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|END PHASE APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2|#]
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "before page loads up"? Only once during webapp's startup? Or *everytime* when you click the link?

Comment: This is definitely not normal behaviour based on the code provided so far. Did you test this on a completely blank playground JSF project? Or is it an existing webapp? If so, other things may have caused this. Perhaps the response is been forwarded/redirected several times for some reason. What output exactly do you see when you click the link only once?

Comment: I repeated the experiment today and the result was a bit different. I updated my post on that.

Comment: What does the browser builtin HTTP traffic tracker say? (press F12 in Chrome/IE9/Firebug)

Comment: Checked - always one request. Earlier also was only one request because my db was hit only once per click. Also I tested more and I noticed that sometimes there is only one lifecycle and sometimes more. And always "additional" lifecycle(s) are executed by different threads, so probably it's Glassfish issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if that's how it's *supposed* to work, but it matches up with my observations of what actually happens.